# App inventor emulator fails to appear on a Mac OSX 10.8.4

Tags: app-inventor

I plan on teaching my High-School students how to build apps using App Inventor but the emulator doesn't show up in the student account of the Mac mini with the latest OSX.

The emulator does show up in my administrator account ( same computer) but it's not appearing in the student account. I usually enable Parental Controls for the student account and from my admin account I give access to specific applications that can be used in the student account.

The Java downloads fine and I am able to open it in the student account but the Android emulator is not showing up at all.

Any ideas other than making an admin account for students? ( not ideal)

Comment: see [these threads](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/app-inventor-instructors/emulator$20mac%7Csort:relevance) in the App Inventor in Education Forum

Answer (score 0):

> **I'm using a Mac, the emulator won't open, and there is no error
>   message.**
>
> There's a permissions issue on shared Macs in that results in the
>   first person to log in being able to use the emulator, but subsequent
>   people cannot. If that's what you're seeing, you can fix it by logging
>   in as an administrator and deleting the directory /tmp/android. You'll
>   have to do this each time a new person logs in.
>   - [Source](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/troubleshooting.html)